# Lasso tool in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, draw

Hay, I'm writing a simple web based image maker, and would like to know if anyone has any idea's how to implement a lasso tool. I'd like to be able to save all the points so that I can easily send them to a database and retrieve them at a later date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a basic plug-in, this would probably look something like this:

```
$.fn.extend({
  lasso: function () {
    return this
      .mousedown(function (e) {
        // left mouse down switches on "capturing mode"
        if (e.which === 1 && !$(this).is(".lassoRunning")) {
          $(this).addClass("lassoRunning");
          $(this).data("lassoPoints", []);
        }
      })
      .mouseup(function (e) {
        // left mouse up ends "capturing mode" + triggers "Done" event
        if (e.which === 1 && $(this).is(".lassoRunning")) {
          $(this).removeClass("lassoRunning");
          $(this).trigger("lassoDone", [$(this).data("lassoPoints")]);
        }
      })
      .mousemove(function (e) {
        // mouse move captures co-ordinates + triggers "Point" event
        if ($(this).hasClass(".lassoRunning")) {
          var point = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
          $(this).data("lassoPoints").push(point);
          $(this).trigger("lassoPoint", [point]);
        }
      });
  }
});
```

later, apply `lasso()` to any element and handle the events accordingly:

```
$("#myImg")
.lasso()
.on("lassoDone", function(e, lassoPoints) {
  // do something with lassoPoints
})
.bind("lassoPoint", function(e, lassoPoint) {
  // do something with lassoPoint
});
```

`lassoPoint` will be an array of X,Y co-ordinates. `lassoPoints` will be an array of `lassoPoint`.

You should probably include an extra check for a "lasso enabled" flag of some sort into the `mousedown` handler, so that you can switch it on or off independently.

Comment: I think the 'if' statement in .mousemove event handler should be -
if ($(this).is(".lassoRunning")) {

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Nice one. I would use hasClass() instead of is() in this case though :-). http://jsperf.com/jquery-hasclass-vs-is-performance/6

Comment: This answer wasn't performance-tuned anyway. You are right, `. hasClass()` is significantly faster. Good find.

Answer (score 2):

Heres a plugin that seems to do just that
http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/examples.html

I haven't used it.

I've never made one, but if you're looking to make your own, id imagine they work like

onmousedown record initial mouse coords(this is the coords of the corner of lasso box)

onmousemove subtract new coords from initial coords to get width and height of div being used for the visual lasso box.

onmouseup, stop listening to mousemove, do something with coords and dimension of any lasso box existing

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a free-form lasso rather than a rectangular marquee.

Comment: @casablanca, however imgselectarea is a brilliant tool!

Comment: I've made a free-form lasso in Adobe Flex before for the image area select and print function. The two niches are first, you have to use "Winding Algorithm" to decide those inside areas when you've done lassoing and secondly, for the marching ants on free form lasso, you can use a diagonal-45-degree-parallel-lines-pattern mask bounding rectangle  to animate flowing up/down in 45-degree to get the marching-ant effect.